# calling a label wtih an output of a varriable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to do something like this:

```
@echo off

:beginning
choice /c:123
if %errorlevel%== 1 set test= aaa
if %errorlevel%== 2 set test= bbb
if %errorlevel%== 3 set test= ccc
call :%test%one
pause
goto beginning

:aaaone
echo phrase
exit /b

:bbbone
echo phrase
exit /b

:cccone
echo phrase
exit /b
```

and I'm trying to get the call :%test%one to call the output of whatever the errorlevel is but it won't recognize the output of the variable "test" for %test% and says that it cant find the label.
Is there a way to get the user to choose what the program calls instead of just using "goto (label)"? Thank you in advance for any advice you might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces after = in these lines:

```
if %errorlevel%==1 set test=aaa
if %errorlevel%==2 set test=bbb
if %errorlevel%==3 set test=ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a different, simpler form, like this:

```
@echo off

:beginning
choice /c:123
call :%errorlevel%one
pause
goto beginning

:1one
echo phrase
exit /b

:2one
echo phrase
exit /b

:3one
echo phrase
exit /b
```